# SQL Server 2014 - How to Exclude records that don't have a certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, not-exists

I have a derived temp table based on transaction dates that looks like mentioned below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Account_No| Customer_Name   | Invoice_No  | Amount | Reason_Comment | Trans_Code |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|12345678  | John Doe        | A23782998   | 326.28 | Payment        |          2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|12345678  | John Doe        | A23782998   | 173.72 | Adjustment     |          3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|12345678  | John Doe        | A23782998   |   0.00 | Paid In Full   |  X         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|23456789  | Bob Marley      | B58787934   | 500.00 | Payment        |          2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|23456789  | Bob Marley      | B58787934   |   0.00 | Paid In Full   |  X         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|89034537  | Eric Clapton    | C78236428   |   0.00 | Paid In Full   |  X         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you may notice, Bob Markey made a payment and his account shows as 'Paid In Full'.
Eric Clapton is smooth. He made a payment earlier and hence is already showing as 'Paid In Full'
John Doe here, needed a little help in the form of an 'Adjustment' so that we could bring his Account Balance to zero and hence 'Paid In Full'

Transactions with Payment were given a Trans_Code of 2, Adjustment 3 and Paid in Full as X.

I would like to Exclude transactions that only have a 'Paid In Full' Reason or X in TransCode.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #temp_table 
WHERE Account_No NOT IN 
     (SELECT Account_No FROM #temp_table 
      WHERE Reason_Comment = 'Paid In FUll'
        AND Reason_Comment <> 'PAYMENT' 
        AND Reason_Comment <> 'ADJUSTMENT')
```

Perhaps, I should use a `NOT EXISTS`

**EDIT:**
This is the table I'm working with. Because I'm specifying a date range, some Accounts only have one line, which is a 'Paid In Full' line because the Adjustments or Payments happened BEFORE the specified Date Range. For example, the last line (Johnson Doe) in the below table. I want to EXCLUDE that last line.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Account_No| Customer_Name   | Invoice_No  | Amount | Trans_No  |Reason_Comment | Trans_Date | Trans_Code|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|12345678  | John Doe        | A23782998   | 326.28 |1234567    |Payment         | 2018-04-01 |         2|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|12345678  | John Doe        | A23782998   | 687.58 |           |Amount Due      |            |         4|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|23456789  | Jane Doe        | B12378299   | 123.56 |2345678    |Payment         | 2018-04-02 |         2|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|23456789  | Jane Doe        | B12378299   | 336.44 |3456789    |Adjustment      | 2018-04-03 |         3|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|23456789  | Jane Doe        | B12378299   |        |           |Paid In Full    |            |         X|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|34567890  | Jonas Doe       | C34567998   | 500.55 |4567891    |Payment         | 2018-04-06 |         2|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|34567890  | Jonas Doe       | C34567998   |        |           |Paid In Full    |            |         X|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|45678912  | Johnson Doe     | D45678756   |        |           |Paid In Full    |            |         X|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you want the results to be?  I find the question unclear.

Comment: This is misleading, just clarify this, do you want to exclude transactions that only paid in full upfront ? so the output that you need is to exclude Eric Clapton from the records as he paid the full amount earlier in one payment, and don't have any adjustments nor installments payments ! is that what are you looking for ? please edit your post and add a clarification with an expected results from the given example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tab t2
                  WHERE t.Account_no = t2.Account_no
                    AND t.Invoice_no = t2.Invoice_no
                    AND (Reason_Comment IN ('Paid In FUll')
                         OR TransCode = 'X')
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

--You can write the query in different way

```
SELECT * 
FROM #temptable 
WHERE Reason_Comment != 'Paid In FUll'  AND trans_code != 'X'

SELECT * 
FROM #temptable 
EXCEPT
SELECT * 
FROM #temptable 
WHERE Reason_Comment = 'Paid In FUll'
OR trans_code = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, your post is not really clear of what do you exactly need to exclude, but from the example and the query you've provided, I concluded that you need to exclude customer who don't have any adjustments or installments plan (People like Eric Clapton from your example), because why you need to keep track of payments that are already paid in full (upfront or earlier than its due) aren't you suppose to follow up with people who has installments payments or adjustments to make sure you get the full payment? 
This is how I understood your question, and this is what makes sense to me (perhaps).

If that's what are you looking for, then you could do this :

**UPDATED (WITH The new provided example)**

```
SELECT
    Account_No, 
    Customer_Name, 
    Invoice_No, 
    Amount, 
    Trans_No,
    Reason_Comment, 
    Trans_Date,
    Trans_Code 
FROM(
SELECT
    Account_No, 
    Customer_Name, 
    Invoice_No, 
    Amount, 
    Trans_No,
    Reason_Comment, 
    Trans_Code, 
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            COUNT(Account_No) OVER(PARTITION BY Account_No) = 1 AND Trans_Code = 'X'            
            THEN NULL 
        ELSE  
           COUNT(Account_No) OVER(PARTITION BY Account_No)
    END  AS NumberOfPayments, 
    Trans_Date 
FROM Trans
) D
WHERE 
    NumberOfPayments IS NOT NULL 
AND (
        CAST(Trans_Date AS DATE) >= '2018-04-01'
    AND CAST(Trans_Date AS DATE) <= '2018-04-06'
    OR  Trans_Date IS NULL 
)
```

This would return :

```
| Account_No | Customer_Name | Invoice_No | Amount | Trans_No | Reason_Comment |           Trans_Date | Trans_Code |
|------------|---------------|------------|--------|----------|----------------|----------------------|------------|
|   12345678 |      John Doe |  A23782998 | 326.28 |  1234567 |        Payment | 2018-04-01T00:00:00Z |         2  |
|   12345678 |      John Doe |  A23782998 | 687.58 |   (null) |     Amount Due |               (null) |         4  |
|   23456789 |      Jane Doe |  B12378299 | 123.56 |  2345678 |        Payment | 2018-04-02T00:00:00Z |         2  |
|   23456789 |      Jane Doe |  B12378299 | 336.44 |  3456789 |     Adjustment | 2018-04-03T00:00:00Z |         3  |
|   23456789 |      Jane Doe |  B12378299 | (null) |   (null) |   Paid In Full |               (null) |         X  |
|   34567890 |     Jonas Doe |  C34567998 | 500.55 |  4567891 |        Payment | 2018-04-06T00:00:00Z |         2  |
|   34567890 |     Jonas Doe |  C34567998 | (null) |   (null) |   Paid In Full |               (null) |         X  |
```

*NumberOfPayments* will count the payments for each account number based on invoice number.
You could change the `CASE` rules as it fits your needs, you could also add a payments order (payment 1, payment 2, payment 3 ..etc) useful for installment payments. All you need to do is just add this line :

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Invoice_No ORDER BY Trans_Code) AS PaymnetNumber
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a5b0f/1)

Comment: I used this exact code for my query but I get an error message 'Incorrect syntax near 'order'. Any ideas why? My code is as follows:
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT Account_No
      ,Customer_Name
   ,Invoice_No
   ,Amount
   ,Reason_Comment
   ,Trans_Code
   ,CASE WHEN Count(Account_No) OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice_No ORDER BY Invoice_No) = 1 AND Trans_Code = 'X' THEN NULL
         ELSE Count(Account_No) OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice_No ORDER BY Invoice_No)
    END AS NoOfPayments
 FROM #temp_table) D
WHERE NoOfPayments IS NOT NULL

Comment: @user1777929 I've updated the query and the demo. try it. It should work probably, even the previous one.

Comment: Yes. I tried that earlier by removing the ORDER BY part. But now I get only 2 rows for each account. Either it is an Adjustment and Paid in Full or it is a Payment and Paid In Full. There are a lot of Accounts that have a Payment, Adjustment and a Paid In Full. But those Accounts don't show a Payment and Adjustment and Paid In Full. They only show as Adjustment and Paid In Full. There is also another Reason_Comment; which is 'AmountDue'. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.   _I will Edit my question to show a revised table of what I'm working with.

Comment: @user1777929 this is because you missed to mention the information that you just added into your post, which is invalidate the above query. tell me, why some customers have NULL(or empty) values in Amount and Trans_Date ? so I update the query

Comment: @user1777929 I have updated the query along with the Fiddle Demo. check them out.

Comment: @user1777929 just I need to mention CAST(Trans_Date AS DATE) is not necessary if your column is DATE, but if is it DATETIME and you need to use the date range by dates only, you need to use this method to get the correct date range.